# Implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm with Networkx, reveicing a print error

Tags: python, networkx, dijkstra

I'm trying to read a file with source target weight values respectively to find the shortest path and print that path with the final weight. I'm using Networkx to use the Dijkstra function. However, when I execute, I receive this notice:
`<function shortest_path at 0x7f9a13c39230>
<function bidirectional_dijkstra at 0x7f9a13c48140>`

I initially used just the `shortest_path` function thinking I somehow messed up using it, thus using the `bidirectional_dijkstra` function.

The file in question has dummy data titled example.txt:

`D1 D5 7
D1 D2 6
D5 D4 7
D5 D3 7
D5 D3 3
D5 D2 4
D2 D2 1
D4 D3 1`

My method in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os.path
import networkx as nx
from sys import argv


#!script, filename = argv
#assigns example to open the file example.txt
example = open("example.txt", "r") 

print("\n This is what we have in our file:\n")

#prints the open file
print example.read()

G =nx.Graph()

for line in example:
    source, target, weight = line.split() 
    nx.shortest_path(G,[source, target, weight])

print ( nx.shortest_path)
print ( nx.bidirectional_dijkstra)
#for some reason, this is printing:
#
#<function shortest_path at 0x7fe480d56230>
#<function bidirectional_dijkstra at 0x7fe480d65140>
```

Comment: you arent actually calling the function. ie `nx.shortest_path` is the actually function, `nx.shortest_path()` would give you the return value.

Comment: So, I should change `nx.shortest_path` to `nx.shortest_path()`?

Comment: well what are you trying to print? looks like you called it properly inside of the while loop but are not capturing the return value

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong; I didn't have the edges defined. I've added the edge to the graph, and it works now. Thanks! I'm getting the results I need.

Comment: I didnt do much but okay. make sure to post your fix as an answer so that others will see what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was receiving the message because I had not properly defined an edge.
Here's the updated code:

```
   import os.path
   import networkx as nx
   from sys import argv


   #!script, filename = argv
   #assigns example to open the file example.txt
   example = open("/example.txt", "r") 


   G =nx.Graph()

   for line in example:
       line = line.split()
       G.add_edge(line[0], line[1], weight=line[2])
       #nx.shortest_path(G,[source, target, weight])

   print nx.shortest_path(G)
   print nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
```